Why "Laß dich nicht den Satan blenden" not "...der Satan..."?
Is Satan here in the accusative because the person (not) letting this happen is the subject? Could this be ambiguous at first glance, with a possible translation of "don't let yourself blind Satan"?
This is from Bach's cantata BWV 54.

Widerstehe doch der Sünde
Sonst ergreifet dich ihr Gift.
Laß dich nicht den Satan blenden;
Denn die Gottes Ehre schänden,
Trifft ein Fluch, der tödlich ist.


Since the grammar is truely a bit strange, compare that the original publication of the text by Georg Christian Lehms had the same: Digitalisation

This is syntactically ambiguous. "Lassen" takes and accusative and an infinitival phrase, which may itself contain an embedded accusative, as it does here; and with poetic license the words can be shuffled around so that it's unclear which accusative is embedded and which isn't, i.e. who blinds whom. There is nothing nonstandard about this.
However, semantically it is obvious that the message is the standard "Don't let Satan blind you" and not vice versa. In fact, it's partially because the message is so clear that the poet can dare to shuffle the words as much.

It would be interesting to understand whether there is a positive reason for this structure. Lass den Satan dich nicht blenden would work just as well with rhyme and meter.

@JonathanHerrera Speculation: in a 4/4 rhythm, the second stressed syllable is on meter 3, and the third on 1. The way it is written has a short vowel (dich) on 3, and a long (Sa-) on 1. The following line has the same rhythm of short and long syllables. Since the two form the paired and rhyming first two lines of a three-line Abgesang, the result is better adapted for the classical Choral form (although, in comparison with the 7-line Lutherstrophe the second Stollen of the Aufgesang is missing).

argh, the stressed syllable on 3 is "nicht". Still, a short vowel.

@ccprog Thanks! That totally makes sense and I consider it highly likely to be the reason.

It's not just possible to translate it like that. Considering modern German it must be translated like that.
However, "don't let yourself blind Satan" doesn't sound like the author's intention.
Maybe the author considers it a sin to blind satan but I have another theory. If we replace "den" with "vom" we get "Lass dich nicht vom Satan blenden".
This would literally translate to "don't be blinded by satan". However, if you allow a little interpreation it would be "don't be tempted by satan".
My best guess is that the usage of "den" in this case is archaic. Maybe there is someone here in the community who studied german grammar throughout the ages who can confirm my guess.

Archaic? Hardly so. It's just the word order that is unusual, if you slightly reshuffle words (and actually, it wouldn't break the meter here), it becomes much clearer: "Lass den Satan dich nicht blenden".
